# sklearn pickled model "Attribute Error: model has no attribute classes_"

Tags: scikit-learn

I built a sklearn model in one PC and pickled it. When, I tried to use the same model in another PC, I get below error:

> Attribute Error:  model has no attribute classes_

When I built the model , I did check

> Model.classes_

It printed the classes. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

it would help knowing the version details of scikit-learn in both the PCs but the information on the [website](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) tells it is possible to happen due to different versions. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Think of `pickle` as a way to dump and load a snapshot of an object **and its environment** at a given moment.

Sometimes the object you deal with does not mean anything by itself . You must provide extra data with it.

That's particularly the case with trained **classifiers**. In your case, `model_classes` works perfectly in your script when you have you data and fitted your classifier. Suppose now that you have dumped the classifier and loaded it later in another script : what are the classes you are talking about ? About what data are we talking about ? ... Got it ?

**What you have to do** then is to **provide additional meta data** when pickling.
[This](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#security-maintainability-limitations) section of `sklearn`'s documentation describes what needs to be pickled alonside the classifier (training data, source code ...).

---

**NB**:

Check first that both versions of sklearn are the same. Sometimes it can be just that.